# How to draw a textured rectangle with Metal

Tags: ios, metal

I'm looking for a most efficient way of drawing a 2-dimensional background in metal. This requires rendering a textured rectangle.

The [basic geometry example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/hello_triangle) shows an example on how to draw a triangle. Is there an easy and non-bloated way to draw a rectangle (a polygon with 4 corners)?

Comment: Draw two triangles (in one draw call). That's either two separate triangles (that happen to shared two vertices) in a triangle list or a single triangle strip that comprises two triangles (so, four vertices).

Comment: @KenThomases Thanks. So to conclude: it isn't possible to draw a rectangle per se, it is always two triangles.

Comment: Yes, basically. It could, of course, be more than two triangles if you want to make more work. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [Basic Texturing sample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/basic_texturing?language=objc) draws a textured rectangle